# ошибки при добавление структуры с __attribute__ в .h файл

Tags: c, gcc

Добавил в заголовочный файл следующие определение структуры:

```
typedef struct {
    float   data[32];
    int     size;
}Mcalc;

Mcalc MCALC __attribute__((section(".DIO")));
```

компилятор выдает следующие ошибки:

```
multiple definition of `MCALC'
first defined here
multiple definition of `MCALC'
first defined here
```

Как можно решить данную проблему ?

Comment: Если вы этот `.h` файл потом включаете в несколько `.c` файлов, то у вас в двух разных единицах трансляции получается свое определение `MCALC`, о чем вам компилятор и говорит. Уберите определение `MCALC` из `.h` файла. А `__attribute__` тут ни при чем.

Comment: Да я включаю .h в двух разных .c файлах.  А как можно убрать MCALC из .h ?

Comment: ```#ifndef HEADER #define HEADER ///code/// #endif```

Comment: Это у меня сделано

Comment: @zhilenkov, ну, вам нужно вот эту строку — `Mcalc MCALC __attribute__((section(".DIO")));` — убрать из `.h` файла и поместить в `.c` файле, где эта переменная (`MCALC`) используется. Если она используется в нескольких `.c` файлах, то вам нужно определить ее в одном `.c` файле, а в других сделать её внешней (`extern`). Или сделать объявить внешней в `.h`. Тут зависит от того, что вам конкретно нужно.

Answer (score 0):

В заголовочном файле делаете только предварительное объявление переменной с помощью `extern`. Без никаких атрибутов.

att.h :

```
typedef struct {
    float   data[32];
    int     size;
}Mcalc;

extern  Mcalc MCALC ;
```

А в одном из файлов реализацию.

att.c :

```
# include "att.h"
Mcalc MCALC __attribute__((section(".DIO")));
```

main.c :

```
# include "att.h"
int main(){
  MCALC = ( Mcalc ) { .size = 0 , .data = { 0 } };
}
```

Comment: Зачем здесь вдруг поменяется каст?

Comment: В Си фигурные скобки не дают повод для автоматического определения типа структуры. Нужно это делать вручную. @mik.ov